# Compose an email in Gmail without seeing my inbox

Tags: gmail

I would like to compose an email in Gmail, but if I open my inbox I find I get distracted with all the emails that have arrived since I last looked.

Is there a URL I can go to to compose an email without seeing the rest of the user interface?

Comment: You guys are right. It would be ideal if they could do just the box (like the one that pops up when you click on an email link for someone else). Unfortunately curiosity will always kill the cat when I see my inbox # increase on the right. Is there anything we can do collectively or individually? There should be a Google Gripe :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check it out:
https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1

props to http://www.arshammirshah.com/technology/gmail-send-compose-email-without-opening-inbox for the link!

Comment: That's better than @Alex's original answer as it doesn't have the folders on the left.

Comment: Great answer! Any idea how to do the same on a mobile device? I can't seem to find a gmail compose link anywhere for a mobile device.

Comment: Stripping away some of the extra stuff, just https://mail.google.com?view=cm on its own seems to work for me too.

Answer (score 5):

You can open directly the *compose* interface by going to `https://mail.google.com/mail/#compose` or `https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#compose`, but this also displays the folders/labels column on the left. I don't think you can go directly to the pop-out compose window (which is what you are looking for, right?)—if you copy its URL and paste it into a new tab, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, the pop out window would be ideal, but your solution is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

In GMail, click on "Compose", then copy the URL from your browser.  It should end in "#compose".  In future, go directly to the URL you've copied.  When I do this, I'm taken directly to the compose screen.